# Boundedness of coefficients.

Tags: functional-analysis

$K$ is a bounded subset of the normed space $(X, \|\|)$.  $X_n$ is a finite dimensional subspace generated by $\{e_1, \cdots e_n\}$.  And we have $$\sup_{x\in K}\inf_{y\in X_n}\|x-y\|\leq A$$

$\forall x\in K$, assume the best approximation of $x$ in $X_n$ is $\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke_k $ i.e. $\|\sum_{k=1}^n a_ke_k -x\|\leq A+\epsilon $, then how to prove that each $a_k$ is bounded, the upper bound of $a_k$ is independent of $x$  and is just related to $K$ . Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n$, being finite dimensional, is a Banach space. Consider the linear map $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k e_k \to (a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ from $X_n$ into $\mathbb R^{n}$. Use Closed Graph Theorem to show that this map is continuous. This gives a constant $C$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k^{2} \leq C ||\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k e_k||^{2} \leq C(||x||+A+\epsilon)^{2}$$ from which boundedness of each $a_k$ follows.